# Need some help in Group by StateID - TSQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Can anyone help me on below scenario I need small help on group by state ID

Below is my query and I am tried to get all the out put in single line .

But I am getting different lines for each year . please help me to get all the output in single row as the State ID is same.

```
SELECT  StateID,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2016 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2016,
(Select count(Fileid) where year = '2016' ) AS TotalFs2016,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2017 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2017,
(Select count(Fileid) where year = '2017' ) AS TotalFs2017,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2018 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2018,
(Select count(Fileid) where year = '2018' ) AS TotalFs2018,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2019 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2019,
(Select count(Fileid) where year = '2019' ) AS TotalFs2019
--FileState
FROM
(
SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs AS FileSize  --, FileState
FROM #Temp1
UNION ALL
SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs --, FileState
FROM #Temp2
UNION ALL
SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs --, FileState
FROM #Temp3
UNION ALL
SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs --, FileState
FROM #Temp4
)t 
where StateID like '570' 
GROUP BY 
t.StateID , year
```

Current out put gives 4 rows for different years like 2016 , 2017 , 2018 , 2019 along with the Size of the files.

Where are I want to get only one row as put with all years data as the ID is same.

I tried to GROUP BY but still does not help .

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Wrap each output field (except StateID) with `MAX()` function. Remove `year`from `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by isn't needed since you only select one stateid

```
SELECT  StateID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2016 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2016,
  count(case when year = 2016 then Fileid end ) AS TotalFs2016,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2017 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2017,
  count(case when year = 2017 then Fileid end ) AS TotalFs2017,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2018 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2018,
  count(case when year = 2018 then Fileid end ) AS TotalFs2018,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = 2019 THEN FileSize END) AS FileSize_2019,
  count(case when year = 2018 then Fileid end ) AS TotalFs2019
--FileState
FROM
(
  SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs AS FileSize  --, FileState
  FROM #Temp1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs --, FileState
  FROM #Temp2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs --, FileState
  FROM #Temp3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT StateID,[Year],FileID,FileTotalSizeMBs --, FileState
  FROM #Temp4
)t
where t.StateID like '570'
```

Comment: You should read about the pivot queries, they are made for problems like these.  I believe SQL Server has them.

Comment: That's a great advice , I will definitely read and go through them . Thanks again.